# Color change in ListView.builder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, user-interface, listview

Color change in ListView.builder

When I get to the layout I fill in the List, this List is passed to ListView and drawn, that is, when you change the mode to night, the color of the tiles does not change until you switch to layout or until you force to redraw ListView itself.

The question is how to change the color of already rendered ListView elements

Creating a ListView is as follows:

```
Widget _taskListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _task.length,
      itemBuilder: (contextItems, index) {
        return _task[index];
      },
    );
  }
```

And here is the card itself, which falls into the List of elements:

```
Widget _cardTask(BuildContext context, int index, TaskModel taskModel) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
      child: InkWell(
        hoverColor: customRed,
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SetTimeScreen(taskModel))
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.black12,
                blurRadius: 6.0,
                offset: Offset(0, 2),
              )
            ],
            color: OtherStaticData.darkMode ? customGray50 : Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(15.0)),
          ),
          child: _cardTaskBody(context, taskModel),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: it seems that you have to rebuild your `ListView` - you can do that by using `setState` or by using some `Theme` stuff (`MAterialApp.darkTheme`)

Comment: I use ```darkTheme``` in ```MaterialApp```

Comment: Now I will try to rebuild ```ListView``` by means of ```setState```

Comment: if you use `MaterialApp.darkTheme` so you need to set `MaterialApp.themeMode` to either `dark` or `light`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution for the problem become architecture pattern BLoC

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31019766)